# Downloading image and comments from 9gag using python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, automation

I want to use 9gag's images and top 10 comments for that image. I'm trying to pull images using python. I don't know how to proceed.

```
BASE_URL = 'https://9gag.com/'

def get_image_soup(section):
    url = BASE_URL + section
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = bs(plain_text)
    return soup

soup = get_image_soup(BASE_URL + 'funny')
```

Looks like the links to articles are in "GAG.App.LoadConfig". How do I pull the links to articles?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the html to get images and the commments. The comments are in different pages than the images, so you need to generate the link for each image and then parse the comments there. To pull the links for articles, you need to get the id of each image and use it to generate the new link. If the id of an image is `avOXW7d` then your url needs to be `https://9gag.com/gag/avOXW7d`.

I would suggest using an API and not parsing the html for this task since it is very time consuming to parse html. Doing a quick Google search, I found out that there are some unofficial APIs for 9gag. Here are some links that you can use. [Link 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/9gag/comments/66l1a3/digging_into_actual_9gag_api/). [Link 2](https://github.com/k3min/infinigag).